# How to write if ,else block for multiple conditions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am new to javascript what is right way to write if and else block with below code i am getting an error on else condition that syntax is not correct. Please let me know what i have implemented wrong.

main.js

```
if (dataRow.opriskYesNo === 'Yes') {
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = 'Y';
} else if (dataRow.opriskYesNo === 'No') {
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = 'N';
} else(dataRow.opriskYesNo === '') {
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = '';
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = '';
}
```

Comment: for the last else... u don't need the (dataRow.opriskYesNo === '')

Comment: else implies that there is no condition

Comment: you are missing another if at the end

Comment: so in that case for the last one I also need else if because i have condition for last one.

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have `else` without any condition in your last conditional code block.

Though the improved version would look like below, I'd say maintain one object with key value and use it.

```
var mappedModel = {'Yes': 'Y', 'No': 'N'};
$scope.opRiskCompleted = mappedModel[dataRow.opriskYesNo] || '';
```

Comment: Thanks its perfect solution with small piece of code. Learned something new today i really appreciate it.

Comment: @aftab Really glad to help you.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a Switch?

```
switch(dataRow.opriskYesNo){
case "Yes":
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = 'Y';
    break;
case "No":
     $scope.opRiskCompleted = 'N';
    break;
default:
     $scope.opRiskCompleted = '';
    break; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(dataRow.opriskYesNo==='Yes'){
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = 'Y';
} else if (dataRow.opriskYesNo==='No') {
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = 'N';
} else {
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = '';
    $scope.opRiskCompleted = '';
}
```